# Translating C POST request to Curl

Tags: html, c, curl, post

I'm trying to translate some c code to python. I need to understand the structure of a POST request the original c code makes. I would like to tranlate the following C code to a cURL command:

```
void nonblock(int sock) {
    int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
    flags = flags | O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags);
}

int pool() {
        int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    nonblock(sd);

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

        memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(poolport);
    memcpy(&servaddr.sin_addr, poolip, sizeof(poolip));

    pollcount++;

        connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    char buffer[1000];



    sprintf(buffer, "POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\ncontent-type: application/octet-stream\r\ncontent-length: %i\r\nhost: %s:%i\r\nconnection: close\r\n\r\n[\"mining_data\", \"%s\"]", 
        workPath,
        (19 + (int)strlen(address)),
        hostname,
        poolport,
        address
    );

    printf("1_____\n%s\n_____\n", 
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 4;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    fd_set my;
    FD_ZERO(&my);
    FD_SET(sd, &my);
    select(sd+1, NULL, &my, NULL, &tv);

    if(!FD_ISSET(sd, &my)) {
        close(sd);
        usleep(500000);
        return -1;
    }

    send(sd, buffer, strlen(buffer), MSG_NOSIGNAL);

    tv.tv_sec = 4;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&my);
    FD_SET(sd, &my);

    select(sd+1, &my, NULL, NULL, &tv);


    if(!FD_ISSET(sd, &my)) {
        close(sd);
        usleep(500000);
        return -1;
    }


    int bytes = read(sd, buffer, 1000);
        // I want what's in buffer here

        close(sd);
        ...
}
```

Buffer is:

```
POST /work HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-length: 107
host: veopool.pw:8880
connection: close

["mining_data", "BONJmlU2FUqYgUY60LTIumsYrW/c6MHte64y5KlDzXk5toyEMaBzWm8dHmdMfJmXnqvbYmlwim0hiFmYCCn3Rm0="]
```

I have tried requesting this same data in cURL as

```
curl -v -d '{"mining_data":"BONJmlU2FUqYgUY60LTIumsYrW/c6MHte64y5KlDzXk5toyEMaBzWm8dHmdMfJmXnqvbYmlwim0hiFmYCCn3Rm0="}' -H "content-length: 107" -H "content-type: application/octet-stream" -H "connection: close" -X POST http://veopool.pw:8880/work
```

After a few seconds I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Internal Server Error</pre>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

Can anyone show me where I'm messing up?

Comment: This causes the server to reply immediately with the error shown above

Comment: Did you try running the c program ? Is it working properly ? Are you trying to translate this [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dystophia/VeoCL/master/client.c) ?

Comment: Yes, it gets data back form the server and proceeds to use it elsewhere in the program

Comment: You are sending `{"mining_data":"BONJmlU2FUqYgUY60LTIumsYrW/c6MHte64y5KlDzXk5toyEMaBzWm8dHmdMfJmXnqvbYmlwim0hiFmYCCn3Rm0="}` instead of `"['mining_data', 'BONJmlU2FUqYgUY60LTIumsYrW/c6MHte64y5KlDzXk5toyEMaBzWm8dHmdMfJmXnqvbYmlwim0hiFmYCCn3Rm0=']"`

Comment: Changing that moves be from "Internal Sever Error" to "Bad Request"

Comment: As per your buffer it should be `"['mining_data', 'BONJmlU2FUqYgUY60LTIumsYrW/c6MHte64y5KlDzXk5toyEMaBzWm8dHmdMfJmXnqvbYmlwim0hiFmYCCn3Rm0=']"`. You may also try removing that content-length now.

Comment: Is it working now ?